# How to join two object in one in template Angular?

Tags: angular

I have the following array:

```
let users = [{id: 1, a: [], b: []}];
```

Template is:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
   <div *ngFor="let joined of user.a + user.b"></div>
</ng-contaner>
```

I need to concat two arrays `a` and `b` in object `user`.

Where is better to do that? In template or component and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Template**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
   <div *ngFor="let joined of user.a.concat(user.b)"></div>
</ng-contaner>
```

**Template and Container**

in template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
   <div *ngFor="let joined of getArray(user)"></div>
</ng-container>
```

in component

```
getArray(user) {
   return user.a.concat(user.b);
}
```

Seems template only solution is better if there is no other manipulation on the array, else go for the manipulation in component.

Comment: everything is correct  but maybe the best way is to create a pipe 

Answer (score 1):

**Templete :**

```
   <div *ngFor="let user of users">
      <div *ngFor="let joined of user.a.concat(user.b)">{{joined}}</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

both previews answer will work fine but there is a problem this `user.a.concat(user.b)` will keep ruining in **every change detection cycle**  so that why create a pipe will be a good practices here.

*concat.pipe.ts*

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'concat'
})
export class ConcatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(a: any[], b:any[]): any {
    return a.concat(b);
  }

}
```

*template*

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
   <div *ngFor="let value of user.a | concat:user.b">{{value}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1j8gyc?file=src/app/app.component.html)